# libGDX Tiled map Как в изометрии узнать getCell?

Tags: java, libgdx

У меня изометрическая карта. И у меня не получается узнать координаты блока, то есть getCell.

```
    //Map
    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map/Castle_Fight.tmx");
    tiledMapTileLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer)tiledMap.getLayers().get(0);
    stageMap = new TiledMapStage(tiledMap);
    tiledMapRenderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
        //InputEvent
    InputProcessor clEv = new GestureDetector(new clEvent(camera, tiledMapTileLayer));
    InputProcessor IPstage = stagePanel;
    InpMult = new InputMultiplexer();
    InpMult.addProcessor(clEv);
    InpMult.addProcessor(IPstage);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(InpMult); 

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    System.out.print(layer.getCell((int)x,(int)y));
    return false;
}
```